# FTP Archiving/Versions

Tags: php, svn, file-upload, ftp

Is it possible to add a command to FTP that creates a copy of the file being uploaded for backup purposes? I am trying to create some sort of Version Control System, but I don't want to have the user be limited to a browser-based upload system or to a specific FTP client.

It would be awesome if FTP had a way to run a PHP script on upload, which would have all of the version control scripts in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a backup system for the relevant file system, which will keep appropriate versions on the backup drive.

As a plus, you can kick off a backup instance when a write completed with inotify (WRITE & CLOSE).

Comment: Hmm... I am on a shared host, I don't think this would work. Also, I was look for something that would let me create a copy of the file with a sort of time-stamp added so you could look at previous versions.